# How to add content on a specific point inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a div with an id (main comment) and more divs underneath with reply id's. I want to dynamically add the content of the comment to the end at the end of the replies. I can't grab the id of the last reply, but I can grab the id of the main comment (which is also the id of the commentbox which is always at the end. Something like this:

```
<div class="commentArea">
<div class="comment_'.id.'"> Something </div>
<div class="reply_'.replyid.'"> What kind of comment is that? </div>
<div class="reply_'.replyid.'"> What kind of reply is that? </div>
<div class="reply_'.replyid.'"> You guys are strange. </div>
<div class="replyToComment_'.id.'"> some button and stuff </div>
</div>
```

I want to add content inside commentArea right before replyToComment_'.id.' ...

I had an idea that probably works and looked like this (I was thinking maybe there was some easier way to do it).

```
<div class="commentArea">
<div class="comment_'.id.'"> Something </div>
<div class="reply_'.replyid.'"> What kind of comment is that? </div>
<div class="reply_'.replyid.'"> What kind of reply is that? </div>
<div class="reply_'.replyid.'"> You guys are strange. </div>
<div class="newReply"></div>
<div class="replyToComment_'.id.'"> some button and stuff </div>
</div>
```

And just add and empty div of newReply at the end of every reply posted...

Any other ideas?

Comment: I'd like a hoverboard. But seriously, what is the question?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/ & class selector

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't quite work that out either. There was something about sharing IDs in there which is never good.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the id's are pure number automatically generated by the php.
But it seems that InsertBefore will do it. @ArunPJohny , If you add it as an answer I will probably be accepting it once I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

.appendTo() of jQuery is what you need:

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: That won't work, as it will just add to the end of the selected div, I have to add something at a specific place inside the div. It seems insertBefore() is going to work, will test it in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I understood your question correctly, but I think [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) would help you.

You will need to wrap your last div i.e. `<div class="replyToComment_'.id.'"> some button and stuff </div>` with some other div and do `.prepend()` on that parent everytime. Like this:

```
<div class='parentContainer'>
<div class="replyToComment_'.id.'"> some button and stuff </div>
</div>
```

And do `$(".parentContainer'").prepend(newComment)` to add comment everytime.

Comment: prepend wouldn't work here as it adds content inside the selected div, I want to add content outside and right before that div.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, you will need to wrap your last `div` inside some other `div` on which you can do `.prepend()` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I thought about few ways to achieve this goal... "If i understand correctly what you were trying to ask"

By this way you do not need even to use ID as a class.... unless there is a specific reason to this?!?!
If not then move the id to id attribute and give it something like this

```
id="2,56" 
2 = the question || post id
56 = the answer id
```

by this way you will have more control on your posts and comments

```
1. if reply_ is an individual class

    $('.reply_')[$('.reply_').length - 1].after(comment);

2. if replyToComment_ is an individual class

    $('.replyToComment_').before(comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("#addtxt").click(function () {
    $("[class^='replyToComment']").before("<div class='newReply'>" + $("#text").val() + "</div>");
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jt84nb23/)